# Is $O(|V||E|)$ polynomial time?

Tags: asymptotics

If an algorithm runs in $O(|V||E|)$, is its running time bounded by some polynomial of $|V|+|E|$? If not, what is its running time called?

Comment: Note that in nearly all applications $E = O(V^2)$, so $O(VE)$ is also polynomial in $V$ (and polynomial in $E$, but that's less useful).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2 \geq 2ab$, it is indeed true that $|V||E|$ is bounded by a polynomial in $|V|+|E|$.